# Reading JSON file parse objects error in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am reading data from S3 bucket using "[select_object_content](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.select_object_content)", everything working for me. I can able to fetch result from s3 JSON file.
But after getting the result I checked the records and its type printing as a string(ie <class 'str'>), but I cannot able to access values inside that object and it's throwing an error.

Code sample

Sample [JSON](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TWST-WEnXyKxviDV9MSA5UhoNeKRn8eH/view?usp=sharing) file attached in S3

```
query = "SELECT * FROM s3object[*]['domain'][*] r where r.id > " + str(start) + " and r.id <= " + str(stop) + " limit " + str(pagesize);
      r = s3.select_object_content(
             Bucket=cache,
             Key= key + '.json',
             ExpressionType='SQL',
             Expression= query,
             InputSerialization={'JSON': {"Type": "Lines"}},
             OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}},
      )
   for event in r['Payload']:
         if 'Records' in event:
             records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
             print(type(records));  // <class 'str'>
             print(records);  // Please see records printing below example 
             print(records['hostname']) // Throwing error - 3 records are printing together so cannot access first record
```

Records are printing like this, I want to access values inside this object

```
{"id":6,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-529.awsdns-02.net.","passive_dns_count":"7"}
{"id":7,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"6"}
{"id":8,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"7"}
```

I tried to parse the string to object like below but it also throwing an error

```
parsed_json = (json.loads(records))
print(parsed_json.hostname)
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Also tried removing utf-8 encoding then printing records like below

I tried to remove utf-8 encoding now getting some valid errors

Now the record type printing as bytes

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

**Record is printing like this way**

```
b'{"id":6,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-529.awsdns-02.net.","passive_dns_count":"7"}\n{"id":7,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"6"}\n{"id":8,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"7"}\n{"id":9,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1983.awsdns-55.co.uk.","passive_dns_count":"6"}\n{"id":10,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1983.awsdns-55.co.uk.","passive_dns_count":"7"}\n'
```

Comment: Could you please share sample contents from this file?

Comment: @amitd sample json google drive link attached, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `eval`. From your snippet

```
records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
records = eval(records)

print(type(records))  ## <class 'dict'>
```

#### Update::

Iterate over them

```
records = records.split()
for doc in records:
    doc = eval(doc)
    print(doc)
```

Comment: I tried getting error in this line 
records = eval(records)

Comment: records = eval(records)
  File "<string>", line 2
    {"id":7,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"6"}

Comment: Can you describe the error more. Also you can try by removing the .decode('utf-8')

Comment: I removed utf-8 now the record type is printing as bytes, I edited my question to include bytes data can you please check

Comment: Dont remove .decode('utf-8').  Also, before using eval using split. It will convert it into list of strings. Then iterate over the list and then use eval function

Comment: records = records.split(); for docs in records: docs = eval(docs)

Comment: ['{"id":6,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-529.awsdns-02.net.","passive_dns_count":"7"}', '{"id":7,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"6"}', '{"id":8,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1288.awsdns-33.org.","passive_dns_count":"7"}', '{"id":9,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1983.awsdns-55.co.uk.","passive_dns_count":"6"}', '{"id":10,"hostname":"amt.in.","subtype":"NS","value":"ns-1983.awsdns-55.co.uk.","passive_dns_count":"7"}']

Comment: Now I am getting an array of records after the split, can you give me an example to access each record. Also, can you edit your answer with this? So I will make it an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Following is code snippet to print hostname based on response from query execution;

```
    for event in r['Payload']:
        if 'Records' in event:
            records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8').split('\n')
            for record in records:
                if len(record) > 0:
                    row=json.loads(record)
                    print(row["hostname"])
```

Comment: Note: If you set `RecordDelimiter` in `OutputSerialization` to something other than `\n`, you'll need to replace `\n` in this snippet with your delimiter.